# Filling up a select dropdown with only some values from an array in a json dataset

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

Using this json input:

```
[
    {
        "tableName": "data",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "id": "att1"
            },
            {
                "id": "att2"
            },
            {
                "id": "att3"
            },
            {
                "id": "att8"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have two select dropdowns, in the first dropdown I get the tableNames from my json file, so the first dropdown has values of data, data1, data2, etc and the user would select a table by selecting its "tableName". In my second dropdown I want only the attribute ids from the previously selected tableName from the first dropdown. I am stuck at this part, as it still iterates through the whole dataset instead of just the attributes of a single data.
This isn't correct but this is what I currently have, it just gets the first attribute for all of my datasets

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = "listData.json";
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('#dropdown-1').append('<option selected="true" disabled>Select Data</option>');
        var i = 0;
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            // APPEND OR INSERT DATA TO SELECT ELEMENT.
            $('#dropdown-1').append('<option value>' + value.attributes[i].id + '</option>');
            i++;
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.filter` to filter your json array based on the value which user has selected from the first dropdown depending on this get required `attributes` and loop through it then append options with required `ids` in second dropdown .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//your json data
var data = [{
  "tableName": "data1",
  "attributes": [{
      "id": "att1"
    },
    {
      "id": "att"
    },
    {
      "id": "att3"
    },
    {
      "id": "att5"
    }
  ]
}, {
  "tableName": "data2",
  "attributes": [{
      "id": "att"
    },
    {
      "id": "att2"
    },
    {
      "id": "att3"
    },
    {
      "id": "att8"
    }
  ]
}]
$('#dropdown-1').append('<option selected="true" disabled>Select Data</option>');
var i = 0;
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
  // APPEND OR INSERT DATA TO SELECT ELEMENT.
  $('#dropdown-1').append('<option value=' + value.tableName + '>' + value.tableName + '</option>');

});
//on change of 1st dropdown 
$(document).on('change', '#dropdown-1', function() {
  var value = $(this).val(); //get value

  //filter json array
  var attribute = $(data)
    .filter(function(i, n) {
      return n.tableName === value;
    });
  //empty second dropdown
  $('#dropdown-2').html("");
  $('#dropdown-2').append('<option selected="true" disabled>Select attributes</option>');
  //loop through attribute
  $.each(attribute[0].attributes, function(index, value) {
    //append datas
    $('#dropdown-2').append('<option value=' + value.id + '>' + value.id + '</option>');


  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown-1"></select>

<select id="dropdown-2"></select>
```